# How to combine multiple email lists in one Excel file?

Tags: excel, list, email

I have about 40 email lists, for a total of 300.000 rows. They are not similarly formatted, as they have slightly different info (i.e. some have age, some don't), but they all have a column for the email addresses. I'm trying to combine them in a single document, keeping only the email addresses and removing duplicate emails.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to  import all excel documents into database ?
Then you can do SELECT  DISTINCT UNION  from database.